# extracting subsring from string using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like this

```
ha regular{{patou0383838}}but if{{coffee}}i love {{tomato}}
```

I need a regular expression in c# that will help me to extract all text starting with `{{` and ending with `}}`. So for instance in the example above, I should be able to have a group of 3 sub strings

```
{{patou0383838}}
{{coffee}}
{{tomato}}
```

I tried various examples that I found on the web but they did not solve my problem.

Comment: Show us one example you´ve tried (or even created yourself), and we´ll be glad to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try like this:

```
\{{.*?\}}
```

or

```
\{\{.*?\}\}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your tokens are sure to be never nested like `{{token {{1}}}}` you can use

```
\{\{([^}]+)\}\}
```

The text enclosed within the braces is captured as group `1`. For example, for a match like `{{coffee}}` the group one would hold `coffee`.

---

Although braces `{}` are used to specify ranges in a regex like `{m,n}` they aren't treated as special characters when included otherwise. So, we can simplify the regex by not escaping them as

```
{{([^}]+)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

`{` and `}` are special characters in regexes, so they need to be escaped.  Also, since you could have more than one match in one line, you need to do a non-greedy match.  The pattern will be something like

```
string pattern = @"(\{\{.*?\}\})"
```

The parenthesis are what are captured, including the `{{` and `}}`